# Netty: Make use of a pooled buffer for writing

Tags: java, netty

I'm currently working on a POC using Netty and till so far it goes very nice and managed to get quite some functionality up and running.

I have a question however about reusing the byte-buffer for writing. In the following example you can see a manually created bytebuffer-response, but it is created for every request and that isn't needed. I would like to make use of 'buf'. I'm currently running a bit in the trial and error mode and I have checked out the examples. Although my case looks very standard, I have not been able to figure out the correct way of making of a pooled buffer.

```
  public class OperationHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {
    private ByteBuf buf;

    @Override
    public void handlerAdded(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
        buf = ctx.alloc().buffer(1024);
        //    System.out.println("Channel handler added");
    }

    @Override
    public void handlerRemoved(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
        buf.release();
        buf = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
        try {
            ByteBuffer response = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
            byte[] operation = (byte[]) msg;
            invoker.invoke(operation, response);
            response.flip();
            ctx.write(Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(response));
        } finally {
            ReferenceCountUtil.release(msg);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void channelReadComplete(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
        ctx.flush();
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
        // Close the connection when an exception is raised.
        cause.printStackTrace();
        ctx.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you happen to come up with a solution? I am in the same situation, and instead of doing pooled direct buffers, I am considering just using a unpooled direct buffer instead and allocate it once.

Comment: I have dropped Netty and use the NIO api directly. The byte-buffers are all recycled.

Comment: I'm sorry you were not able to use Netty.  However Netty provides buffer pooling in its core.  Have you seen [PooledByteBufAllocator](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/5725e804bcfbd0c76e0f11e7911a76970eb06c8c/buffer/src/main/java/io/netty/buffer/PooledByteBufAllocator.java)?